# Как с помощью LINQ найти элемент с минимальным значением поля, а не само это значение?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть массив объектов класса `A`.

```
class A
{
    public double value;
}
```

Как с помощью LINQ найти **элемент** с минимальным значением value, а не само это значение, как  произошло бы в случае `arr.Min(a => a.value)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204169/4928642

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не встречал конструкции, которая выполняла бы это действие за один Linq-запрос. А за два сделать довольно просто:

```
double min = arr.Min(a => a.value);
var result = arr.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == min);
```

2 вариант: Реализовать в Вашем классе интерфейс `IComparable<T>`:

```
class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public double value;

    public int CompareTo(A other)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(other.value);
    }
}
```

Тогда метод `Min()` можно вызвать так, и он вернёт объект класса A с минимальным значением поля `value`:

```
var result = arr.Min();
```

Comment: Вообще-то `Aggregate` :)

Answer (score 7):

С помощью Linq это возможно, но неэффективно. Более простым решением будет написать соответствующий метод; к примеру так:

```
public static TItem MinByKey<TItem, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

    var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Collection is empty.");

    TItem minItem = enumerator.Current;
    TKey minKey = keySelector(minItem);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        TKey key = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
        if (comparer.Compare(key, minKey) < 0)
        {
            minItem = enumerator.Current;
            minKey = key;
        }
    }

    return minItem;
}
```

Тогда задача сведётся к вызову

```
arr.MinByKey(a => a.value);
```

Comment: Почему не эффективно?

Comment: @Anatol Альтернативными вариантами являются:

1. Поиск минимума, затем поиск индекса этого элемента -- два прохода по коллекции.

2. Преобразование элементов в кортежи `(элемент, индекс)`, затем поиск минимума и извлечение индекса из кортежа -- один проход, но необходимо создавать кортежи. Если тип кортежа значимый (Value type), то такой вариант, в принципе, является оптимальным, иначе будет дополнительное выделение памяти.

Answer (score 5):

Раз уж мы подняли этот вопрос: самый простой метод — не строить собственный велосипед, а использовать готовое решение. Например, можно [установить пакет `MoreLinq` через nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) и использовать просто

```
using MoreLinq;
```

```
A best = arr.MinBy(a => a.value);
```

---

А начиная с .NET 6, `MinBy` [доступно](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.minby) и без дополнительного пакета. (Спасибо @Exploding Kitten за напоминание.)

Comment: начиная с .NET 6, `MinBy` доступен как часть LINQ, дополнительные пакеты не нужно ставить

Comment: Они решили весь MoreLinq в стандартную библиотеку перенести? :)

Comment: @Grundy Почему бы и нет? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#system-linq-enhancements

Answer (score 2):

```
a.OrderBy(e => e.value).First();
```

В один короткий запрос, но это не эффективно.

Comment: Можно лучше, хотя и подлиннее :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = array.Aggregate((r, x) => r.Value < x.Value ? r : x);
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/80oSKs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class A
{
  public double Value;
  public static implicit operator A(double x) { return new A() { Value = x }; }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var array = new A[] { 1.7, 2.3, -7.8, -11.1, 4.5, 42 };
    var a = array.Aggregate((r, x) => r.Value < x.Value ? r : x);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, array[3]));
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
-11.1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так чуть полегче будет?..

```
List<A> res = arr.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(g => g.First()).ToList()[0];
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ох, и что же у нас будет, если `var arr=Enumerable<int>.Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);`?

Comment: @Zufir, а что будет в этом случае?

Comment: Написал немного не то, что хотел. Прошу прощения. Исправил.